# Foundation 4 Nesting

Tags: zurb-foundation

When nesting grids in Foundation 4 do I have to wrap the nested elements in a div with a class that has the attribute row?

For example, here is my current code:

```
<ul id="games" class="row">
    <li class="small-6 large-3 columns">
        <ul class="row">
            <li class="large-5 columns">Image</li>
            <li class="large-7 columns">
                <p>£35 Free</p>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Deposit:</dt>
                    <dd>£10</dd>

                    <dt>Balance:</dt>
                    <dd>£45</dd>
                </dl>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the example above the second UL has the class row, does this class need it?

I can't help think that there's to much nesting going on in my example. It doesn't feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the example above the second UL has the class row, does this class
>   need it?

I would say it does need it only because of the following reason. Removing the `row` class from the inner container element will make it push its content into a smaller area. Adding the `row` class reduces the margin and allows you to have a wider content area.

So why would you need it? Unless you have a good reason why you would want to have those extra spaces (margin) around your container element, then you do need to add the `row` class.